# Using Keys To Move Image Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to figure out how to move an image using arrow keys on my keyboard with Javascript.

Right now my index.html file has images and they're loaded on my site, but I can't figure out the JS part to make them move with my keys. This is the html syntax that I used in my `index.html` file:

`<img src="images/example.png" alt="example/>`

I know it's not much, but I'm just really stuck right now. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the JS that I have tried so far:

```
let image = document.querySelector('images');
let moveBy = 10;

window.addEventListener('start', () =>{
 });

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) =>{
   switch(e.key){
      case 'ArrowLeft':
         images.style.left = parseInt(images.style.left) - moveBy + 'px';
         break;
```

Comment: I edited with what I have tried so far.

Comment: `.addEventListener('key left'` ... no such event, did you mean `keydown` or `keypress`?

Comment: Sorry yeah I meant 'keydown'.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a working example built on your code.

```js
let i = document.querySelector('img');
let moveBy = 10;

window.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
  const top = i.style.top ? i.style.top : 0
  const left = i.style.left ? i.style.left : 0
  switch(evt.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      i.style.left = (parseInt(left) - moveBy) + 'px';
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      i.style.left = (parseInt(left) + moveBy) + 'px';
      break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
      i.style.top = (parseInt(top) - moveBy) + 'px';
      break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
      i.style.top = (parseInt(top) + moveBy) + 'px';
      break;
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  transition: 200ms;
  top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the image to bring focus to this snippet, then you can use the arrow keys to move the image</p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```